# Reconnecting CiviCRM DB in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, migration

I recently changed from Drupal to Wordpress, and am having some trouble connecting WP to my existing CiviCRM database.

I installed the CiviCRM for Wordpress plugin (and set up a new, empty database for CiviCRM). Then I edited the civicrm.settings.php file to connect to my old CiviCRM database (that I had been using with Drupal). I know the settings are correct, and yet something is wrong. The CiviCRM menu does not appear; the Dashboard appears ugly as if there is no CSS; I cannot access some admin pages (like "Resource URLS") but I can access others (like the Admin Console, by manually typing in the URL, yet as with the Dashboard there is no CSS being applied).

Can someone shed some light on what is happening, and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 3):

Try these, in this order:

- Check that the `CIVICRM_UF` value in civicrm.settings.php has been updated to reflect the changed host CMS
- Try visiting `/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/admin/setting/updateConfigBackend&reset=1` to make CiviCRM recognise the shift from Drupal to WordPress
- Clear the contents of your `civicrm_uf_match` table
- Apply instructions from [Moving an Existing Installation to a New Server or Location](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Moving+an+Existing+Installation+to+a+New+Server+or+Location) to your situation. (This is a huge list of "tricks", only some will apply to your situation.)

Comment: None of that worked... eventually I gave up and emptied the civicrm.setting table in the database and imported a fresh one from the new install of CiviCRM. I lost some of my config settings, but it kept all of the important data. It took a bit of time to re-configure the database, but it is working now.